# AngularJS, changing the data in a view without div disappearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a little wizard/survey in `AngularJS` which loads in data to a variable, `$scope.styles`. I've set up a plunkr for ease of use here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1S542YE7xlO2P4zyhzu0?p=preview

Pretty simple. I show each object to the user in succession, which loads in the pertinent images and displays them for the user. clicking "yes/no" at the bottom of the images it loads in the next gallery. There is a big of lag between the refresh here (Plunkr seems to be loading it quite quickly, but this is not the case on my production server so it's even more noticable) which causes the window size to momentarily be much smaller plus all the content below the `ng-repeat` jumps to the top of the screen.

What's the best way to prevent this from happening? Is CSS the only solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `<img>` elements have a size of 0 until the user's browser loads the image file.  Try changing the image tag to `<img ng-src="{{img}}" width="100" height="100"/>` and you'll notice no more flicker.  If possible, have the server return these attributes with the image url data.

Comment: So setting a static width/height on the images is the only solution? (Surely returning the width/height of the images wouldn't work as that happens when the URL comes in too, so the screen flash would still happen?)

Comment: The `<img>` elements don't exist until the URL is known (angular is rebinding to the array of images).  It does look like angular appends the elements individually, but the lag between appending items to the DOM is probably not visible.

Comment: Also, you could pre-load the next and prev set of images. That way there won't be a delay. This is common technique used in lightboxes/slideshow viewers.

Comment: From a usability standpoint, I personally get annoyed when buttons move around, so I would put the button in a fixed location (or put the images in a fixed height `<div>`

Comment: @winkerVSbecks good point, that goes way back to the day of image rollovers before CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add height to the images wrapper div ( style="height:300px" or, better, as a class).

That way the wrapper will stay fixed sized when images change and when you have less then three rows of images.